# ArrayFormula Only Populating When Not Empty

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, filter, array-formulas, google-query-language

I have the following formula `=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ARTIST_FILTER_MENU="", TRUE, IF(ARTIST_FILTER_MENU=Data!B2:B, TRUE, false))), COUNTA(Data!B2:B), 1)` that will populate TRUE/FALSE values depending on whether data matches a selection in a dropdown menu. And if the dropdown menu is empty, the Boolean result defaults to TRUE.

When the dropdown menu is not empty, the formula works fine, but when it is empty, only the first row is populated.

No dropdown option selected (expected output):

T
T
T
T
T

No dropdown option selected (actual output):

T

After struggling with it for a bit, I figured out it had to do with the line `ARTIST_FILTER_MENU=""` where I haven't used the A#:A format that is usually required for the ArrayFormula function. I found a temporary solution by checking against a random empty cell range instead of "", or is there a better way that I should go about this?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF(ARTIST_FILTER_MENU="", TRUE&IFERROR(Data!B2:B/0), 
 IF(ARTIST_FILTER_MENU=Data!B2:B, TRUE&"", FALSE&""))), COUNTA(Data!B2:B), 1)
```

[image]

```
=QUERY({TRACK_NAME_HELPER_RNG, RELEASES_DATA_RNG, RELEASES_HELPER_RNG}, Helpers!$A$11&
 " WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL 
     AND Col"&Helpers!$B$3&" = 'TRUE' 
     AND Col"&Helpers!$B$5&" = 'TRUE'", 1)
```

[image]

Comment: I have created a copy of the sheet which can be found here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZlhtzCk7iFfeJn7QDoNXwf_FcptWV1TewAiGghVBP_0/edit?usp=sharing

Your solution does appear to fix the TRUE/FALSE outputs, but for whatever reason, my query (which checks against the Booleans) still doesn't respond to the empty cases.

Comment: More specifically, when nothing is selected in the dropdowns in the Dashboard, since everything evaluates to TRUE, it should display all of the data.

Comment: Note: With my temporary solution of refencing an empty cell, this issue does not occur.

`=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ARTIST_FILTER_MENU=K2:K, TRUE, IF(ARTIST_FILTER_MENU=Data!B2:B, TRUE, false))), COUNTA(Data!B2:B), 1)`

Comment: @dan try the updated answer

Comment: Just tried it, seems to work at times and then not for others. Can you try selecting "oneheart" as the artist in the dropdown to see if the query works correctly for you?

Comment: while leaving the "label" dropdown empty.

Comment: @dan fixed try first fx again

Comment: This is working now, thanks! Could you explain both the edits that were made? `TRUE&IFERROR(Data!B2:B/0)` and `IF(ARTIST_FILTER_MENU=Data!B2:B, TRUE&"", FALSE&"")`

Comment: @dan sure. `Data!B2:B/0` creates `#DIV` error coz nothing can be divided by 0. we wrap it into `IFERROR` to remove errors and we are left with the empty column so when we attach `TRUE` to it we get a column of TRUE (at this stage it's important to mention that this column is formatted as a text string and not as boolean) then, by adding `$""` to `TRUE` and `FALSE` we also convert those booleans to text strings. now our query (that is by design buggy) will recognize the whole column as with one formatting so it will not leave out rows we expect to see